# Getting error with sleep and argument in sh script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm doing something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
END=3
time_w = 1
for ((i=1;i<=END;i++)); do
    # do something
    sleep time_w
done
```

but I'm getting

```
sleep: invalid time interval ‘time_w’
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `$time_w`. You need the `$` in front of `bash` variables when they're not inside arithmetic expressions (`((...))`).

```
#!/bin/bash
END=3
time_w=1
for ((i=1;i<=END;i++)); do
    # do something
    echo "$i sleeping for $time_w"
    sleep "$time_w"
done
```

Comment: Woah...some reason I didn't `time_w=1` in the script.

Answer (score 3):

You have made two mistakes:

- In `bash`, there should be no spaces around `=` in variable declaration, so the declaration should be:

  ```
  time_w=1
  ```
- In the command `sleep time_w`, you are supposed to take the value of the variable `time_w` i.e. `"$time_w"`, not the variable itself:

  ```
  sleep "$time_w"
  ```

Comment: use "$", but still get the same error, how to solve this.

Comment: @twlkyao Hard to say without seeing the full thing..could you please make it a new question?

Comment: @heemayI I have solved the problem, it was because I worte a shell script in Windows and push it to Android, the  "0A"and the ”0D 0A" problem. Thanks all the way.